# How to remove css property in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
if(prev_clicked)
{   
    $("#accordion li a.category").css('background-image', 'url("img/off_all_channel.png")');                    
    $("#accordion li a.comment").css('background-image', 'url("img/on_all_online.png")');                   
    $(".icha0").removeProperty("background-color");
    $(".icha0").removeProperty("opacity");
}
else
{   
   $(".icha0").css("background-color","#D5D5D2");
   $(".icha0").css("opacity","0.70");
}
```

I am trying to remove two css properties that I added but It seems not working.
Any though?

Comment: Also, please try Google before posting here. I have no doubt the first result for the exact title you posted here would return an acceptable result. I have no idea where you got `.removeProperty()` from.

Comment: @Christian Varga, whats funny is, now that he has posted this question, it IS the first google result. The second result is another correct stack overflow answer. Third is "removeProp()" and fourth is "removeAttr()", both of those are wrong.

Answer (score 521, accepted):

You can remove them by:

```
$(".icha0").css({ 'background-color' : '', 'opacity' : '' });
```

Comment: It's a bit too late to answer but I think this is important. You must keep in mind that this will only remove the element's attributes defined in the "style" attribute. This will NOT take any effect If they are assigned to a class or similar.

Comment: If you need to remove a property set via a class, you can set to 'inital' instead of ''

Comment: If a property has been set in a class in a stylesheet, none of these methods will work. The only thing that's worked for me is to use `removeClass()` to remove the class from the element altogether.

Comment: You can also pass CSS properties in camelCase JS variables naming convention as follow: $(".icha0").css({ backgroundColor : '', opacity : '' });

Answer (score 114):

You can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to remove css property as well, like this:

```
$(".icha0").css("background-color","");
$(".icha0").css("opacity","");
```

As mentioned in the jquery documentation:

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. $('#mydiv').css('color', '') — removes that property from an element if it has already been directly applied,

Comment: From jqeury css: "It does not, however, remove a style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or <style> element"

Answer (score 56):

To remove the in-line CSS property use:

```
$('.className').css({propertyName: ''});
```

To remove the whole in-line style of an element use:

```
$('.className').removeAttr('style');
```

I've also found this suggestion to remove the CSS property from styles (separate file) use:

*$('.className').style.propertyName = '';*

**BUT** I couldn't get it to work at all, so I'm putting it here just FYI.

Comment: $('.className').style.propertyName = ''; must be $('.className')[0].style.propertyName = ''; - but it's abolutly nonsense

Answer (score 33):

Either you can set the properties back to blank:

`$(".icha0").css("background-color","");`

Or you can change the code to use classes defined in a CSS file:

```
$(".icha0").addClass('properties'); 
$(".icha0").removeClass('properties');
```

Comment: Helped removed jagged edges due to nested 3d perspectives. I was frustrated trying to remove one of the perspectives in order to fix the anti alias issue, this post saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

I was having this problem but I have not seen any solution here that satisfies the OP. Most of the solutions suggest getting rid of the entire style attribute which is not worth it.

I used jQuery's [prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

```js
var styleObject = $('my-selector').prop('style'); 

styleObject.removeProperty('background-color');
```

Answer (score 8):

**with jquery**

```
  $('#ID').removeAttr("style")
```

**withoyt jquery**

```
document.getElementById("ID").removeAttribute("style")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

We have two ways, either you can directly remove the applied CSS style class which is applied to DOM element or remove the applied CSS style from element

```
//Remove the class associated with element

$('#ID').removeClass("cssClass");

//Remove the CSS style from DOM element

$('p').css({"color":""});
```

Comment: There is nothing new in this answer, it's pointless to repeat other answers.

Answer (score 6):

Alternate option, that works around some problems.

Add a new class to the element, and give the properties the value **inherit !important**, eg:

css

```
.clearCSS {
    background-color: inherit !important;
}
```

jquery

```
$(".icha0").addClass('clearCSS');
```

Answer (score 6):

This is literally a copy paste from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405689/how-to-remove-css-property-in-jquery/20090851#20090851), and I use it to clear CSS style that I added with jQuery in a previously executed function.

To remove the in-line CSS property use:

```
$('.className').css({propertyName: ''});
```

To remove the whole in-line style of an element use:

```
$('.className').removeAttr('style');
```

OR by ID:

```
$('#idName').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove all CSS property in JQuery the following code can be use:

```
    $(".selector").removeClass().removeAttr('style');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
        require(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function($) {
            if ($('#p_method_use_reward_points').prop('checked')) {
                $('.test').show();
                console.log('working');
            }else{
                $('.test').hide();
                console.log('not working');
            }
            $('#submit_reward').on('click', function (e){
                let getPoints = $('#custom_reward_set').val();
                let checkField = $('#custom_reward_set').prop("readonly");
                // alert(getPoints);
                if (!getPoints){
                    alert('PLease add reward points');
                }
                if (getPoints) {
                    $("#custom_reward_set").prop("readonly", !$("#custom_reward_set").attr('readonly'));
                    if ($('#custom_reward_set').is('[readonly]')) {
                        $("#custom_reward_set").css({
                            "background-color": "#EBEBE4",
                            "border": "1px solid #ABADB3", "cursor": "not-allowed"
                        });
                    }else{
                        $('#custom_reward_set').removeAttr('style');
                    }
                }
               e.preventDefault();

            })
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you need to **remove** and not **update** a specific property you can simply use  **removeProp** and not **removeProperty** :

```
$(".icha0").removeProp("background-color");
$(".icha0").removeProp("opacity");
```