# CSS not updated when hiding rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a table with the odd and even rows with a different CSS style `tr:nth-child(2n){...}`, and when I filter them with a textbox and jQuery, I hide() all the rows except the ones that match my criteria.

The problem is that now the rows remain with the current style (as I assume they keep the position despite they can't be seen), so the new odd and even rows doesnt match the CSS pattern. 
How could I fix it?

Comment: Post some code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow this example:

```
jQuery('tr:visible').filter(':odd').css({'background-color': 'red'});
jQuery('tr:visible').filter(':even').css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
```

Check here:

http://jsfiddle.net/KSL7j/1/

Hope it helps

**Update**

You can check this other example with odd and row CSS classes.

As CAbbott suggested in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KSL7j/21/

Comment: I created a css class-based variation on your answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/KSL7j/21/

Comment: Yes but one thing is for sure that is not possible in pure CSS.

Comment: A javascript solution is needed and adding CSS classes odd and rows and then manipulate them with javascript seems a valid approach.

Comment: you can feel free to modify your answer with my example if you want. I didn't put it as an answer from me since it was just a variation of what you did.

Comment: ok i will since my example was easy to code for any developer i think it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: How would you do to set no background-color?
I prefer your answer that the one with the classes, but thanks to all of you guys :)

Comment: Thank you, just found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405689/how-to-remove-css-property-in-jquery :)

Comment: Didn't work since when set bg back to none, it applies the nth-child selector, so both have to be set to some style. ty :)

Answer (score 0):

nth-child checks for the nth-child, not for the nth visible child or th nth whatever-styled child (hide() just adds display:none and nothing more...) and will never do.

I see two possible solutions:

1.add classes even/odd after filtering, just asking for the visible ones and then use your css on those classes

untested code:

```
var rows = $(tr[@display=block]);
rows.each(function(){
  var index = rows.index(this);
  if(index%2==0){
    $(this).addClass('even');
  }
  else{
    $(this).addClass('odd');
  }
}
```

2.really remove the rows, not just hiding them

Comment: Option 2 is not really an option for filtering. What if the user uses the backspace? How would you return the deleted rows?

Answer (score 0):

when you use hide() it is just set the display to none.

the structure of the dom is not modify so the nth-child do not work as you expected

you need to remove the even tr to get the effect you want.

if you want reset the rows. you can hold them in a variable and restore them back

```
var rows = $("tr");
var even = rows.filter(":even");

$("#trigger").click(function () {
    even.hide();
    even.remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R2gBt/

Comment: As I mentioned in Ria Elliger's post, deleting isn't a good option for simple table filtering.

Comment: I thought that solution, but removing the rows and adding back seemed quite "a lot of work" for such a thing as the table appearance

Comment: all solution has its tradeoff. you can choose the best to adjust your requirement. i think @alexoulu provides a good solution. you can modify  to adjust your need. :)