# Change or remove CSS using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using elementor for one of the website and it generates following CSS

```
.elementor-3440 .elementor-element.elementor-element-8fae002 .elementskit-navbar-nav > li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: var( --e-global-color-accent );
}
```

when URL link have `href="https://example.com/#menu"`

and when URL link is`href="#menu"` above mentioned CSS is not generate. It is creating design break for me as i need to use absolute url for links as i have to add new pages to website as before it was single page website.

I have tried to remove this CSS using following jQuery but it not working

```
$(".elementor-3440 .elementor-element.elementor-element-8fae002 .elementskit-navbar-nav > li.current-menu-item > a").css('color','');
```

I simply want to remove this css using jquery

```
.elementor-3440 .elementor-element.elementor-element-8fae002 .elementskit-navbar-nav > li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: var( --e-global-color-accent );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove css property in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405689/how-to-remove-css-property-in-jquery)

Comment: what do you see in F12? maybe the style that you add override by the original one

Comment: i sdont see css value of jquery rather autogenerate css `.elementor-3440 .elementor-element.elementor-element-8fae002 .elementskit-navbar-nav > li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: var( --e-global-color-accent );
}`

Comment: maybe try to add class to this element and in css add to this class your wanted style(i think first try to `console.log` the element to see if you have any result maybe it does not find this element)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
$('.elementor-element-8fae002').css('color','initial');
```

Comment: you can also use 'black' (or whatever other color you wish that element to have as a color)

Comment: I am already using blank it still take the value on main css defined in question

Comment: Hm. Can you edit then the theme stylesheet using a child theme setup?

Comment: Like just go and change that in the theme core CSS using a child theme, so your edits don't get wiped at theme update? I know it's hacky but it would work well i think.

Comment: Its is auto generate by Elementor cant change it, for this reason i am trying jQuery to target this css

Comment: I see. Then if it's generated, can you try to use the console with the jQuery code to see if it will override it *after* it is loaded? Maybe your jQuery code is loaded before the Elementor generation, so it's actually overriding your jQuery command. Let it load in the browser, then use the console to input the jQuery command. If that works, then try to place the jQuery snippet later in the chain?

Comment: I had even tried that also as i have put my code in window.load()... event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238529/discussion-between-avia-and-learning).